# Java Program Logical Error. The IF..Part is not working/Executing

Tags: java, if-statement

**Hello Guys,** 
I was writing a code for **bank portal** and I stuck onto a creepy error.
I have a **login()** Function which is called through switch case present in the main function. But whenever I put login details and login **My else part get executed even if the condition is true**. Can you please check whats wrong. I'm a beginner to java programming.

I would also love to hear some suggestions on what new functionality should I add to this code.

Also, rate the quality of my code, I would love to hear from you.

```
package e.banksolutions;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Date;
public class EBankSolutions {

    long accountNumber;            // Variable for Storing account number
    long accountNumberGenerator=0000;   // Variable for generating and assigning account number
    String AccountHolderName;     // Variable for Storing account holder name
    String AccountType;           // Variable for Storing account type in string
    int AccTypeNumVal;
    long accountBalance;          // Variable to Store Current Account Balance. 
    String password;                //27-06-2018
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

public void createAccount() throws InterruptedException
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner variable for accepting value from user
    System.out.println("----------------Welcome to Account Creation Portal-------------------");
    //accountNumberGenerator++; //Incrementing the account number generator var
    accountNumber=rand.nextInt(1000);; //assigning the account number
    System.out.println("Enter Your Name(Without Space Between Name) : ");
    AccountHolderName=scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter New Password : ");                //27-06-2018
    password=scan.next();                                       //27-06-2018
    System.out.println("Enter Your Account Type Savings/Current");
    AccountType=scan.next();

   /* if(AccountType == "Savings"){
        AccTypeNumVal=1;
    }
    else if(AccountType == "Current"){
        AccTypeNumVal=2;
    }*/

bal:System.out.println("Enter your starting balance : ");
    accountBalance=scan.nextLong();
    if(accountBalance<5000){
        System.out.println("Oops!!! Your Account balance should be minimum 5000 or more.\nYou need to fill the form again.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Account Created Successfully.\nYour Account Number is: "+accountNumber+" Please Note it Down.");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    //Delay code below
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.flush();
}

public void DisplayAccount() throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println("Displaying Account Information for Account Number : "+accountNumber);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Account Number  : "+accountNumber);
    System.out.println("Account Name    : "+AccountHolderName);
    System.out.println("Account Type    : "+AccountType);
    System.out.println("Account balance : "+accountBalance);
    System.out.println("Your Password   : _Hidden_"); //27-06-2018
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.flush();
}

public void DepositAmount() throws InterruptedException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner variable for accepting value from user
    long depositAmt;
    System.out.println("---------------Welcome to Deposit Portal----------------");
    System.out.println("You are Depositing amount for Account Number: "+accountNumber);
    System.out.println("\nEnter the Amount to Deposit : ");
    depositAmt=scan.nextLong();
    accountBalance=accountBalance+depositAmt;
    System.out.println("Amount Deposited Successfully.. \nUpdated Balance: "+accountBalance);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.flush();
}


public void WithdrawAmount() throws InterruptedException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner variable for accepting value from user
    long withdrawAmt;
    System.out.println("---------------Welcome to Deposit Portal----------------");
    System.out.println("You are Withdrawing amount for Account Number: "+accountNumber);
    System.out.println("\nEnter the Amount to Withdraw : ");
    withdrawAmt=scan.nextLong();
    accountBalance=accountBalance-withdrawAmt;
    System.out.println("Amount Withdrawn Successfully.. \nUpdated Balance: "+accountBalance);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.flush();
}

public void login() throws InterruptedException
{
    int ch=0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    long accNum=0;
    String passWd="0";
    System.out.println("Enter Account Number : ");
    accNum=scan.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Enter Your Password  : ");
    passWd=scan.next();           
    if (accNum==accountNumber && passWd==password) {
        System.out.println("Logged In Successfully with account number: "+accountNumber+"\n-------------------------------------");   
        System.out.println("Choose Option Number From Below Menu");
        System.out.println("1.Deposit Amount\n2.Withdraw Amount\n3.Display Account Info\n4.Close Account\n5.Exit");
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: DepositAmount();
                    break;
            case 2: WithdrawAmount();
                    break;
            case 3: DisplayAccount();
                    break;
            case 4: System.out.println("You cannot close your account. Feature Coming Soon...");
                    break;
            case 5: System.exit(0);
                    break;
        }
    } 
    else if(accNum!=accountNumber && passWd!=password) {
        System.out.println("You have Entered Incorrect Account Number or Password. Please Check Again.");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.flush();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Unknown Error Occured. Try Agian Later");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.flush();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


EBankSolutions()
{
    accountNumber=0000;
    AccountHolderName="UNDEFINED";
    AccountType="UNDEFINED";
    accountBalance=0000;
    accountNumberGenerator=0000;
    AccTypeNumVal=9;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner variable for accepting value from user
    EBankSolutions a1 = new EBankSolutions();
    int ch;
    int i=0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to Bank E Portal\n");
   while(i!=5)
   {
    System.out.println("Select any Choice Number From below menu...");
    System.out.println("1. Create Account\n2. Login\n3. Exit Portal");
    System.out.print("Enter Your Choice Code 1-4: ");
    ch=scan.nextInt();
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: a1.createAccount();
                break;

        case 2: a1.login();
                break; 

        case 3: System.exit(0);
                break;

    }

   }
}
```

}

Comment: There is a SE site for code reviews: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You'll find no one will want to review your code here. Likewise, make sure you read [ask] because SO is a terrible debugger, and few will want to debug your code for you. If you are a new coder, the single most important skill you will ever learn is to debug your own code. See: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: That all being said, almost certainly your confusion lies with how you are testing values in your if statements. It is almost certainly a mistake when using `==` instead of `.equals()` to compare Strings, for example. https://stackoverflow.com/q/767372/1531971 You are encouraged to start at the beginning and ask yourself what are the exact conditions you are testing and assert those conditions as being met (even with println debugging).

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems preventing your login function from working. Firstly you're checking [string equality with ==](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/) when you're checking the password. This doesn't work because in Java Strings are objects and not primitives.

Next you're using your scanner to scan into passWd when it looks like you mean to be scanning it into password. In your version password is always null.

With these changes your function looks like this:

```
public void login() throws InterruptedException
{
    //snip
    System.out.println("Enter Your Password  : ");
    password=scan.next();           
    if (accNum==accountNumber && passWd.equals(password)) {
        //snip
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java Strings are object you cant compare 2 objects with `==` operator in a meaningful way. You must alway use  `equals` method for that. When you check equality using `==` it will check whether 2 variables are referring to the same object.

you have to change `if (accNum==accountNumber && passWd==password)`

to `if (accNum==accountNumber && passWd.equals(password))`

Answer (score 0):

Where is the value of "ch" coming from?

You print a list of options but you do not appear to read the users reply at any point.

Comment: **Ohh I forgot that too**. I have updated the code and Got the results. Thank you Sir